# Getting child-comments of a comment on Reddit with Praw in Python

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm using praw to scrape information from a reddit thread. I can use `r.get_submission(thread).comments` to give me all the comments in a thread, but now I want to iterate through all of those comments and get the child comments.

Here's what I have:

```
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent="archiver v 1.0")
thread = "https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/4h4o7s/what_do_you_regret_doing_at_university/"
r.login(settings['username'], settings['password'], disable_warning=True)
submission = r.get_submission(thread)

for comment in submission.comments:
    #this works, prints out the comments text
    print(comment.body)

    #now i want to get the child comments that are replied to this comment
    commentSubmission = r.get_submission(comment.permalink)
    #ideally comments[0] should show me first reply, comments[1] the second. etc
    print(commentSubmission.comments[1])
```

This throws `IndexError: list index out of range`. I'm using the method of trying to  get the comment as a submission because it's similiar to a solution I saw here when I was researching https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/1kxd1n/how_can_i_get_the_replies_to_a_comment_with_praw/

My question is: Given a praw `comment` object, how can I loop through all the child comments that are replies? I want to get all the comments that are direct replies to another comment object.

For example, in the example thread in my program, the first comment is `Not going out freshman year`I want to get the response comments like `Meh, I never went out at all in college.` and `Your story sounds identical to mine`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a simple as `comment.replies`, it returns the same kind of iterable as `submission.comments` with `Comment` and `MoreComments` Objects, the latter for more comments at the same level.

Some example code:

```
submission = r.get_submission(thread)
process_comments(submission.comments)

def process_comments(objects):
    for object in objects:
        if type(object).__name__ == "Comment":
            process_comments(object.replies) # Get replies of comment

            # Do stuff with comment (object)

        elif type(object).__name__ == "MoreComments":
            process_comments(object.comments()) # Get more comments at same level
```